# in fprintf: error fault access violation at address 0x000000 ,read of address 0x00

Tags: c

I've run the following code in Borland C and got following error:

> Thread stopped. j:\bc5\bin\file\pro001.exe:fault access violation at
>   0x4043cc : read of address 0x12.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()                                 
{  
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen ("C:\Users\MEYSAM\Desktop\1.txt","w+");
fprintf (fp,"This is testing for fprintf ...\n");
fputs ("that is output filename by reference.",m);
fclose (fp);   
}
```

Comment: Check if `(fp == NULL)` and fail befoire attempting to read from `fp`..

Comment: What is `m`? Where is it defined?

Comment: I think that \ should be escaped as \\

Comment: You need to escape those \, compile with warnings

Answer (score 1):

Probably the `fopen()` failed, returning a `NULL` file pointer.

You must always check that I/O operations succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{  
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen ("C:\\Users\\MEYSAM\\Desktop\\1.txt","w+");
            // ^ using \\ instead of \, you need to escape the \ character

  if (fp == NULL)  // << checking if file could not be opened
  {
     printf("Could not open file.\n");
     return 1;
  }      

  fprintf (fp,"This is testing for fprintf ...\n");
  fputs ("that is output filename by reference.", fp);
                                             // ^ replaced m by fp
  fclose (fp);   
}
```

Comment: Tnx. it was great.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did not check if the `fopen` has been succeeded. Another problem is that in your code you wrote:

```
fputs ("that is output filename by reference.",m);
```

in which `m` is undefined and should be the name of the file, so it should be `fp`.

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fputs.htm) you can find the usage of `fputs`.